# Webpack imported class' function is undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm getting a TypeError from webpack when using a function from an imported class.

I get `TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6_clients_FilesClient__.a.upload(...) is undefined`

I'm exporting my class with:

```
export default(FilesClient = new FilesClient());
```

and importing it into my component with:

```
import FilesClient from "clients/FilesClient";
```

and when I use the client like this:

```
acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {
    FilesClient.upload(file, this.props.proposalId)
    .then(data => {
    ....
```

the type error is thrown. I'm not sure why this is... I'm able to log the object as well as the function to the console and the request is made successfully but, the react app crashes before the response comes back as ok.

This is the same way that I've exported/imported several other clients, however I've only used those to make GET requests so far... Not sure why this one is messed up. I can take the function out of this client class and it's fine, just want to figure out the problem with Webpack.

Just for reference here's the class with the function that Webpack says is undefined:

```
import Client from "./Client";

class FilesClient extends Client {
  upload = (file, proposalId) => {
    const url = `/api/proposals/${proposalId}/uploadfile`;

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file, file.name);

    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    }).then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        console.log(response);
        throw Error("File upload failed", response);
      }
      return response.json();
    });
  }
}

export default (FilesClient = new FilesClient());
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
export default new FilesClient();
```

Try this it should give you desired result, What you are doing now is wrong as it is an assignment and it returns nothing.

Here is codesandbox link
[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wo0xjj6p6w)

Comment: I edited your example to reflect how I'm using my class and it works fine... I'm also able to import and use another client with getter functions in the same manner just fine. So it seems like it's isolated to this one FilesClient class. [Edited Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vj3571w403)

Comment: I did try your solution and it was still erroring out in the same way